# selenium error invalid character in identifier

Tags: selenium, jupyter-notebook, selenium-chromedriver

Selenium requires a driver to interface with the chosen browser. Firefox, for example, requires geckodriver, which needs to be installed before the below examples can be run.

after installing chrome driver for selenium in path directory

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
# this is tested on Firefox or you can use "webdriver.Chrome()"
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(‘https://www.facebook.com/')
sleep(5)
browser.close()
```

Comment: What's the exact error stack trace? I do see an compilation error here `‘` it should be `'` or `"`

Comment: File "<ipython-input-6-03de1cc6ad3d>", line 5
    browser.get(‘https://www.facebook.com/')
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Comment: already explained how to resolve that, Please read the first comment.

Comment: vote to close `Not reproducible or was caused by a typo
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.`

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

...implies that there is a syntax error at *`line 5`* i.e. in the *url string* you have passed through `get()` method.

---

As @cruisepandey correctly pointed out, you need to pass the *`url_string`* within single quotes i.e. `'...'`:

```
browser.get('https://www.facebook.com/')
```

or within double quotes i.e. `"..."`:

```
browser.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
```